# "Pending Payment" status for Check/Money Order payment method

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, order-status, payment-methods

Is it possible to change the default status of the order at any stage of the processing to "Pending Payment" if the payment method selected is "Check/Money Order"?

Answer (score 3):

Im taking it you are on Magento 1.7 from your tag.

Here is a way you can try.

**STEP 1**

Go to System -> Order Statuses

Click - Create New Status

Status code enter 'pendingcheque'

Status Label enter 'Pending Cheque Payment' (Or whatever you want it to say)

Save the Status

**STEP 2**

Go to System -> Order Statuses

Click - Assign status to state

Select your new created status from the drop down

Select 'New' from the Order State drop down

**STEP 3**

Go to System -> Configuration

Click Payment Methods on left

Select Check/Money Order

Your new Order Status should now be available in the New Order status Drop Down.

Hope this helps.

Jamie

Answer (score 2):

Pending Payment is already a status in Magento, and is the default status and state for orders created using Check / Money order for payment. The state it is assigned to is 'New', and by default there are no other statuses assigned to the New state except for Pending.

```
System > Configuration > Payment Methods > Check/Money Order:
```

**Payment Method**

[image]

**Pending Status/State:**

[image]

Comment: The whole point of the question was how to make it so that orders created with this payment method are assigned to "Pending Payment" and not "Pending"

Comment: Are you looking to rename it, or is there something special about the Paypal status code `Pending Payment`?

Comment: I am not looking to rename it but I need to add another transitional status of "Payment Pending" where it goes to "Processing" not when I select "Ship" but "Payment Received" either manually or automatically like in the case of PayPal.

Comment: If this is for receiving checks in the mail and you're manually depositing them, you're the one who is going to have to click 'Invoice' to move the product into that status. In that case, you'll be adding a new status as described by Jamie.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the status to processing, then you simply need to invoice the order once payment is made.

I took it you wanted the original status to be set as pending payment so its clear, is this not the case.

You can add Processing as a default state to Check/Money Order before any payment is received or assign a status to this also is this what you want to do? If so a few minor code changes would be required to allow processing to be a default state.

Your other option is to create your own statuses and assign them to a state, eg processing, new etc. When you do this you can go into the order, at the bottom you have a drop down with the available status options you created, you can then select these from the available options and click submit comment this will change the status and display in the orders list.