# How do i add new order statuses in the dropdown other then "Pending"

Tags: payment, order-status, status, order-state

I tried going through these steps here but it didn't seem to work. I want Check / Money order to have a default status as processing instead of pending.

**Enterprise/Commerce 2.2.6**

---

STEP 1

Go to System -> Order Statuses

Click - Create New Status

Status code enter 'pendingcheque'

Status Label enter 'Pending Cheque Payment' (Or whatever you want it to say)

Save the Status

STEP 2

Go to System -> Order Statuses

Click - Assign status to the state

Select your new created status from the drop down

Select 'New' from the Order State drop down

STEP 3

Go to System -> Configuration

Click Payment Methods on left

Select Check/Money Order

Your new Order Status should now be available in the New Order status Drop Down.[image]

The above steps were from this post: ["Pending Payment" status for Check/Money Order payment method](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5592/pending-payment-status-for-check-money-order-payment-method)

When i change it "new" in the DB it creates processing in the dropdown like so:

[image]

Unfortunately, i believe that's going to make every order go straight to processing which is not the desired outcome. Also there is only one status now which is processing. There has to be a way to append more than one status and be able to select which one you want. Otherwise why would they of created these as dropdowns.

[image]

Comment: @ARUNPRABAKARAN M your edit changed the sense of the question! In Step `Stores > Config > Sales > Payment Methods: Check / Money Order` there can't be created a status. The original question had something else in step 1.

Comment: @HelgeB you're correct it originally said: Go to System -> Order Statuses

Comment: I fixed it again @HelgeB

Comment: Still looking for a little bit of help here. Thanks in advance.